# In VBA, how to extract the string before a number from the text

Tags: excel, vba, string

From `ActiveWorkbook.name`, I would like to extract the strings that are before (left side of ) the numbers. Since I want to use the same code in multiple workbooks, the file names would be variable, but every file name has date info in the middle  (yyyymmdd).

In case of excel file, I can use the below formula, but can I apply the same kind of method in VBA?

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},ASC(A1)&1234567890))-1)
```

Example: MyExcelWorkbook_Management_20200602_MyName.xlsm

In above case, I want to extract "MyExcelWorkbook_Management_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic thing you could do is to replicate something that worked for you in Excel through `Evaluate`:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str As String: str = "MyExcelWorkbook_Management_20200602_MyName.xlsm"
    Debug.Print Evaluate(Replace("=LEFT(""X"",MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},ASC(""X"")&1234567890))-1)", "X", str))
End Sub
```

Pretty? Not really, but it does the job and got it's limitations.

Comment: Pretty! thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Monica, you are welcome. Please don't forget to accept a working answer if it has helped. Upvote any helpfull answers too if you got enough reputation. See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you don't know how.

Comment: Thank you for tour link, sorry I'm new to here. I clicked on the check mark in the top left corner, but I'm not sure that's right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions to extract any letters / underscores before the number as well

```
Dim str As String

str = "MyExcelWorkbook_Management_20200602_MyName.xlsm"

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "^\D*"
    .Global = True

    MsgBox .Execute(str)(0)
End With
```

Gives:

> MyExcelWorkbook_Management_

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for the suggested improvements - have updated

Comment: Rethinking my first comment; using `"^\D*"` would rule out the need to `.Test` and you can just immediately `.Execute` (and the `IgnoreCase` to be scratched). Excuse my first comment, sometimes thinking twice about a problem brings out better insight =)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know this method!

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to use the `Mid`function to look for the first numerical character in your input string, and then cut your input string to that position.
That means we need to loop through the string from left to right, look at one character at a time and see if it is a digit or not.
This code does exactly that:

```
Option Explicit

Sub extratLeftText()

Dim someString As String
Dim result As String
someString = "Hello World1234"

Dim i As Long
Dim c As String 'one character of your string

For i = 1 To Len(someString)
    c = Mid(someString, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(c) = True Then 'should write  "If IsNumeric(c) = True AND i>1 Then" to avoid an "out of bounds" error
        result = Left(someString, i - 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

MsgBox result
End Sub
```

Last thing you need to do is to load in some workbook name into your VBA function. Generally this is done with the `.Name` method of the `workbook`object:

```
Sub workbookName()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

MsgBox wb.Name

End Sub
```

Of course you would need to find some way to replace the `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` line with code that suits your purpose.